# mapped type: Property to item

Tags: typescript, mapping, discriminated-union

Consider this code:

```
type A = { k: 'a.a', u: string } | { k: 'a.b', v: string };
type B = { k: 'b.a', w: number } | { k: 'b.b', x: number };
```

Each item in the list has a key `k`, which is unique. So

```
type AandB = A | B;
```

yields the overall union.

I am trying to create a mapped type such that:

```
type Map = {
  [k in AandB['k']]: <the respective item in AandB> AandB[k] wont work.
}
```

If applied, the compiler should validate such an object:

```
const m: Map = {
  "a.a": { k: 'a.a', u: 'test' }
  …
  …
  …
}
```

How can I get the respective Item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible through some Type Generic trickery:

```
// Get the type of a union based on the value (V) and lookup field (K)
type DiscriminateUnion<
  T,
  K extends keyof T,
  V extends T[K]
> = T extends Record<K, V> ? T : never;
```

Then:

```
type Map = {
  [k in AandB['k']]: DiscriminateUnion<AandB, 'k', k>;
};
```

Then, map should be strictly typed as you pointed out:

```
const map: Map = {
  'a.a': { k: 'a.a', u: 'example' },
  'b.a': { k: 'b.a', w: 0 },
  'b.b': { k: 'b.b', x: 1 },
  'a.b': { k: 'a.b', v: 'Example' }, // TS won't let you change the ids 
// or variable names unless they match the respective object key type.
};
```

## Why does this work?

Its important to understand union types as not just one type, but sort of an array of many.

When the following comparison is done:

```
T extends Record<K, V>? T : never
```

we are actually comparing every single type of this union with the following ternary (if-statement).

Since `Record` represents an object where keys are of type `K` and values are of type `V`, we end up doing a loop of every type in `AandB` and only returning the type where the `K: 'k'` is equal to the specified key `V` which could be `a.a, b.b, etc`, otherwise returning never which is ignored if at least one element is returned.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this. Seams like I have to change something fundamental… Would it be possible to turn `AandB` into a tuple/array like type, such that: `[{k:…}, {k:…}]` each item in union becomes an item in the list?

Comment: @philipp After thinking about it a little more and a little research, I found a place where I did this before and replicated it as an edit to my answer. It achieves exactly what you want, try it out!

Comment: Wow, that looks pretty promising, even if I do not really understand that :) I guess it's meant to be `type DiscriminateUnion …` ??

Comment: @philipp fixed the typo and edited my answer with an explanation. Let me know if you have any other questions :)

Comment: Thanks for that! Your explanation really helped me to gain a bit more understanding here. Is there any resource, besides the »official handbook« that covers those topics and concepts, probably with some examples I can understand :)

Comment: Sorry for the super late answer, but if you're still curious on how to really understand the more advanced forms of TS, I recommend checking out TS 'challenges', like here: https://github.com/type-challenges/type-challenges. The ones in `hard` will really challenge your TS knowledge :)